# Using Format-Table with pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

I want to use Format-Table -Autosize with pscustomobject.

I want the equivalent of :

```
Get-Process | ft Id,ProcessName -AutoSize
```

I tried (although the output is located in the center)

```
Get-Process | %{
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ID   = $_.Id
                ProcessName  = $_.ProcessName
            }
}
```

It works but when I use Format-Table -Autosize it is not working, it add new titles with new lines.

```
Get-Process | %{
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ID   = $_.Id
                ProcessName  = $_.ProcessName
            } | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pipe is in the wrong location.

```
Get-Process | %{
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ID   = $_.Id
                ProcessName  = $_.ProcessName
            } 
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You were telling it to output a single table for every element instead of using the pipeline as intended.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is under our nose and we don't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You're piping to `Format-Table` at the wrong point:

```
Get-Process | % {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ID   = $_.Id
        ProcessName  = $_.ProcessName
    } 
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```